# Container Semantics and Functional Style in D

Tags: functional-programming, pass-by-reference, d, pass-by-value, move-semantics

Does containers in D have value or reference semantics by default? If they have reference semantics doesn't that fundamentally hinder the use of functional programming style in D (compared to C++11's Move Semantics) such as in the following (academic) example:

```
auto Y = reverse(sort(X));
```

where `X` is a container.

Comment: I'd hate to tell you this but it's something in between... sometimes it's more like reference semantics, sometimes it's more like value semantics. :\

Comment: I don't understand the reference to C++11 move semantics - how are move semantics related to functional programming? (D has move semantics too, btw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether containers have value semantics or reference semantics depends entirely on the container. The only built-in containers are dynamic arrays, static arrays, and associative arrays. Static arrays have strict value semantics, because they sit on the stack. Associative arrays have strict reference semantics. And dynamic arrays mostly have reference semantics. They're elements don't get copied, but they do, so they end up with semantics which are a bit particular. I'd advise reading [this article](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html) on D arrays for more details.

As for containers which are official but not built-in, the containers in std.container all have reference semantics, and in general, that's how containers should be, because it's highly inefficient to do otherwise. But since anyone can implement their own containers, anyone can create containers which are value types if they want to.

However, like C++, D does not take the route of having algorithms operate on containers, so as far as algorithms go, whether containers have reference or value semantics is pretty much irrelevant. In C++, algorithms operate on iterators, so if you wanted to sort a container, you'd do something like `sort(container.begin(), container.end())`. In D, they operate on ranges, so you'd do `sort(container[])`. In neither language would you actually sort a container directly. Whether containers themselves have value or references semantics is therefore irrelevant to your typical algorithm.

However, D does better at functional programming with algorithms than C++ does, because ranges are better suited for it. Iterators have to be passed around in pairs, which doesn't work very well for chaining functions. Ranges, on the other hand, chain quite well, and Phobos takes advantage of this. It's one of its primary design principles that most of its functions operate on ranges to allow you to do in code what you typically end up doing on the unix command line with pipes, where you have a lot of generic tools/functions which generate output which you can pipe/pass to other tools/functions to operate on, allowing you to chain independent operations to do something specific to your needs rather than relying on someone to have written a program/function which did exactly what you want directly. Walter Bright discussed it recently in [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/component-programming-in-d/240008321).

So, in D, it's easy to do something like:

```
auto stuff = sort(array(take(map!"a % 1000"(rndGen()), 100)));
```

or if you prefer UFCS (Universal Function Call Syntax):

```
auto stuff = rndGen().map!"a % 1000"().take(100).array().sort();
```

In either case, it generates a sorted list of 100 random numbers between 0 and 1000, and the code is in a functional style, which C++ would have a much harder time doing, and libraries which operate on containers rather than iterators or ranges would have an even harder time doing.

Comment: Static arrays don't just sit on the stack, the storage of any variable depends on a lot of factors and static arrays aren't limited to local function variables.

Comment: @jA_cOp They're just like ints or floats or whatnot in that they're on the stack unless you specifically put them on the heap or put them in an object which is on the heap, which is completely different from dynamic or associative arrays. Their memory is allocated exactly where they're put (which is most typically on the stack) rather than them pointing to memory elsewhere, which is why I phrased it that way.

Comment: I didn't know about `take`! Is this example kind of like Haskell's concept of lazily evaluated sets?

Comment: @Nordlow Many range-based functions return lazy ranges, similar to what you would get in Haskell. `map` and `take` are both examples of this. It saves unnecessary computations that away and allows for the usage of infinite ranges. Though actually I just realized that I made a mistake in this particular case. `sort` needs to operate on a random-access range, in which case the result of `take` isn't going to work. I'll have to tweak it so that it calls `array` before calling `sort` (so that the result of `take` gets put in an `array`).

Answer (score 2):

### In-Built Containers

The only in-built containers in D are slices (also called arrays/dynamic arrays) and static arrays. The latter have value semantics (unlike in C and C++) - the entire array is (shallow) copied when passed around.

As for slices, they are value types with indirection, so you could say they have both value and reference semantics.

Imagine `T[]` as a `struct` like this:

```
struct Slice(T)
{
    size_t length;
    T* ptr;
}
```

Where `ptr` is a pointer to the first element of the slice, and `length` is the number of elements within the bounds of the slice. You can access the `.ptr` and `.length` fields of a slice, but while the data structure is identical to the above, it's actually a compiler built-in and thus not defined anywhere (the name `Slice` is just for demonstrative purposes).

Knowing this, you can see that copying a slice (assign to another variable, pass to a function etc.) just copies a length (no indrection - value semantics) and a pointer (has indirection - reference semantics).

In other words, a slice is a *view* into an array (located anywhere in memory), and there can be multiple views into the same array.

### Algorithms

`sort` and `reverse` from `std.algorithm` work in-place to cater to as many users as possible. If the user wanted to put the result in a GC-allocated copy of the slice and leave the original unchanged, that can easily be done (`X.dup`). If the user wanted to put the result in a custom-allocated buffer, that can be done too. Finally, if the user wanted to sort in-place, this is an option. At any rate, any extra overhead is made explicit.

However, it's important to note that most algorithms in the standard library don't require mutation, instead returning lazily-evaluated range results, which is characteristic of functional programming.

### User-Defined Containers

When it comes to user-defined containers, they can have whatever semantics they want - any configuration is possible in D.

The containers in `std.container` are reference types with `.dup` methods for making copies, thus slightly emulating slices.